# Windows 8 embedded sporadic/randomly goes to sleep. Possibly network related

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, sleep, embedded

I have 2 PC's running Windows 8.1 Embedded. Last week after months of up-time they went to sleep. There was no windows event logging to match this, only PnP messages from plugging my keyboard in to wake them up.

This coincided with some networking issues and loss of connectivity. The PC's are wired in to a router that connects over 3/4G. The network issues are now resolved and the customer has not reported any issues since.

I am certain all power settings are correct (after all, they have been up for months) so does anyone know why loss of network connectivity has somehow resulted in the PC's going to sleep? I have combed the BIOS and found no related config.

Thank you,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may come in search of something similar, I believe I have found the cause of random sleeps.

The PC's were not actually going to sleep, only the monitors were going off. This was because of some scheduled WinSat calls when the PCs' were Idle. The PC's were flagged as idle (as far as task scheduler is concerned, CPU and IO input wise) because the network was down so there was nothing for the software I had running to do.

When WinSAT is called it puts the power config into High-Performance 'theme'. Inside High-Performance the displays were set to go off after 15minutes. As it took over 15 mins for the PC's to go 'idle' it would immediately turn the displays off. After, it reverts back to balanced power 'theme' but does not turn the display back on.

I am going to write a scathing e-mail to Microsoft about this bug. My company and I chose an embedded platform to minimise things such as this; why on Earth would I care about WEI on an embedded platform?